# Adding syntax-highlighting to "processing" tag?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

The Processing language ([tag wiki here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)) is based on Java but uses a simplified syntax from Java. Would it be possible to add automatic syntax-highlighting for questions tagged with [processing](/questions/tagged/processing) using Java syntax?

Comment: @BillyMailman AFAIK associating a tag with a certain language is something SE needs to do.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The proposed dupe says _" If a language that could be applied to a tag is already on the list, please raise a feature request here on Meta to have it deployed on the network."_ @Billy. The Java highlighting already exists; this is just a request to associate the Java highlighting with a new _tag_ (that tag being within the purview of SE).